# 'int' object is not subscriptable error occurred when I tried to use 'for in' for this following code in python

Tags: python, for-loop, for-in-loop

```
digits = [2006 , 2007]
for i in digits:
    
    df_i['dateInt']=df_i['year'].astype(str) + df_i['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)+ df_i['day'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
    df_i['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_i['dateInt'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
    df_i['date'] = df_i['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    dff_i = pd.DataFrame({'date' :df_i['date'] , 'Summary' :df_i['Summary'],'Precip Type':df_i['Precip Type'], 'Temperature (C)':df_i['Temperature (C)'], 'Wind Speed (km/h)':df_i['Wind Speed (km/h)'],'Pressure (millibars)': df_i['Pressure (millibars)'], 'Humidity':df_i['Humidity']})
print(dff_i)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input and expected output?

Comment: In this form the question is almonst unanswerable. Please also add the full traceback.